# Index and Joins

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I know the the how how does indexing works for the table...

but I want to know if I fire the following join statement and index on the column   CustomerID in this case index play any role if yes then how or is there any other way to create index for that ??

```
SELECT o.OrderID
     , o.CustomerID
     , c.CustomerName
     , o.OrderDate
  FROM Orders o 
  JOIN Customers c
    ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
 order 
    by o.CustomerID;
```

and tables are like

Orders table:

```
    +----------------------+------------+------------+
    | OrderID              | CustomerID | OrderDate  |
    +----------------------+------------+------------| 
    | 10308                | 2          |1996-09-18  |
    | 10309                | 37         |1996-09-19  |
    | 10310                | 77         |1996-09-20  |
    +----------------------+------------+------------+
```

Customers table:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName                        ContactName    Country    
         1  Alfreds Futterkiste                 Maria Anders   Germany    
         2  Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  Ana Trujillo   Mexico    
         3  Antonio Moreno Taquería             Antonio Moreno Mexico
```

Comment: give us ur expected output

Comment: yes ...but i want to know does index play any role in join statement and how?

Comment: The explain statement will tell you if an index is used (most likely it will be used)

Answer (score 0):

When `JOINing` tables, the Optimizer first decides which table to start with.  In your particular example, there is no `WHERE`, but there is an `ORDER BY`.  So, the Optimizer will *probably* decide to start with the table being `ORDERed`.  This *may* avoid a sort.

Assuming it starts with `Orders` in an attempt to avoid the sort, you need this on `Orders`:

```
INDEX(CustomerID)
```

The second table in the `JOIN` is, therefore, `Customers`.  To reach into `Customers` after looking into `Orders`, you have `ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID`.  So, you need this on `Customers`:

```
INDEX(CustomerID)
```

(Note:  Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is an index, there is no need to add the `INDEX` if you already have `PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)`.  It would help if you showed us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.)